# Powerpacks DataRepeater Control - Image not getting loaded in picture box

Tags: winforms, picturebox, datarepeater, powerpacks

I have a winform powerpacks datareapter control having a picture box. This is the code snippet from the classes.

### DisplaySystemUsersControl.Designer.cs

```
this.picBoxUserImage.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
this.picBoxUserImage.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Image", this.UserBindingSource, "User_Image", true));
this.picBoxUserImage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
this.picBoxUserImage.Name = "picBoxUserImage";
this.picBoxUserImage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 93);
this.picBoxUserImage.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
this.picBoxUserImage.TabIndex = 0;
this.picBoxUserImage.TabStop = false;
this.picBoxUserImage.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.picBoxUserImage_Click);
```

### DisplaySystemUsersControl.cs

```
public DisplaySystemUsersControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.dataRepeaterAccounts.DataSource = this.UserBindingSource;
    LoadAccountData();
}    

private void LoadAccountData()
{
    SystemUserBusinessClass oSystemUserBusinessClass = new SystemUserBusinessClass();
    List<SystemUserEntity_Only_For_UI_Binding> obj = oSystemUserBusinessClass.GetSystemUsersForUI();

    BindingSource tempUserBindingSource = (BindingSource)dataRepeaterAccounts.DataSource;
    obj.ForEach(oSystemUserEntity_Only_For_UI_Binding => tempUserBindingSource.Add(oSystemUserEntity_Only_For_UI_Binding));
}
```

### SystemUserEntity_Only_For_UI_Binding.cs

```
public class SystemUserEntity_Only_For_UI_Binding
{
    public string User_Id { get; set; }

    public string User_Name { get; set; }

    public byte[] User_Image { get; set; }
}
```

User ID and User name is getting loaded. But Image is not getting loaded. `SystemUserEntity_Only_For_UI_Binding.User_Image()` is holding the image byte array.

Can anybody please tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: I don't see `this.picBoxUserImage.Image` being set anywhere in your sample code.

Comment: @LarsTech - I am setting the binding property in the designer class.                                  `this.picBoxUserImage.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Image", this.UserBindingSource, "User_Image", true));`

Comment: Are you converting the byte array to an image somewhere?

Comment: I tried with converting the byte array into image . Still it is not binding.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should look something like this:

```
public class SystemUserEntity_Only_For_UI_Binding
{
  public string User_Id { get; set; }
  public string User_Name { get; set; }
  public Image User_Image { get; set; }
}
```

The byte array needs to be translated into an image somewhere in your code:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgBytes)) {
  this.User_Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: I tried this code also. But unfortunately it is not working. I used this code. This is working.                                                         `private void dataRepeaterAccounts_DrawItem(object sender, DataRepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
 Image img;
 img = ((SystemUserEntityOnlyForUIBinding)((BindingSource)((DataRepeater)sender).DataSource).Current).User_Image;
            ((PictureBox)e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls["picBoxUserImage"]).Image = img;
        }`

Comment: If that is working, please create a new answer and mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
public void BindRepeater (DataSet dsObj)
{
   pictureBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
   pictureBox1.DataBindings.Add("ImageLocation", dt, "Photo");
   dataRepeater1.DataSource = dsObj;

 }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: //assuming dataset has required fields
public void BindRepeater (DataSet dsObj)
{
       pictureBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
       pictureBox1.DataBindings.Add("ImageLocation", dt, "Photo");
//ImageLocation is the property of the pictureBox1and Photo is column name in dataset
       dataRepeater1.DataSource = dsObj;

}